# Simple npapi plugin gives "no plug-in available to display this content" error message

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi

I've downloaded the sample from http://code.google.com/p/npapi-chrome-plugin-helloworld-example/
Do not worry about building from the source, the built .dll and the manifest and a test.html is in the sampleplugin folder.

Problem: If I open the test.html in Chrome (latest) I've got a gray rectangle with the message "no plug-in available to display this content".

What am I missing?
(Can anyone reproduce this? Again, no need to build, just 10 sec to download and launch test.html)

Thx for answers

- The npsimple.dll is really in the plugin subdirectory relative to the manifest.json.

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "npapi_helloworld",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "a small helloworld example of npapi.",
"plugins":[
    {"path":"plugin/npsimple.dll","public":true}
]
}
```

test.html

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    test = document.getElementById("pluginObj");
    alert(test.sayHello());
}
</script>
</head>
<embed id="pluginObj" type="application/x-helloworld"> 
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your related code here.., i hope you have registered NPAPI with manifest file?

Comment: chrome.exe --plugin-startup-dialog see if your plugin had been loaded . also you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785781/npapi-plugin-not-loaded-on-chrome

Comment: The manifest.json is in the same directory with the test.html. Is there anything I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

The "manifest_version": 2, must be added to manifest.json :-(. (Why?)

Comment: Looks like [v1 is being phased out](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html).